# Select fields containing at least one non-space alphanumeric character

Tags: sql, null

(Sorry I know this is an old chestnut; I have found similar answers here but not an exact answer)

I frequently hand type this kind of query from a console so I am always looking for easier to type solutions

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tbl_loyalty_card  
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID REGEXP "[0-9A-Z]"; -- exact but tedious to type
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tbl_loyalty_card  
WHERE  LENGTH(CUSTOMER_ID) >0; -- could match spaces
```

Do you have anything quicker to type even/especially if it's QAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter, but will match any non-space, not just alphanumeric.

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_loyalty_card  WHERE TRIM(CUSTOMER_ID) != '';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already pretty short; what I mean you are looking to gain at most something like 15% (10 chars out of 70).

If it is the speed and convenience you are after then I have a hunch that maybe one of these options might be better for you:

- script it (stored procedure, shell script)
- use keyboard macros
- start building the application to automate your tasks

Comment: Good idea,  I will add another keyboard macro

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to mark the answer as useful (for accepted answer as well). http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

A combination of LENGTH and TRIM should work better:

SELECT *
FROM  tbl_loyalty_card
WHERE  LENGTH(TRIM(CUSTOMER_ID)) >0;